# Fix a malformed string?

Tags: python, string

I have data coming from a TCP line as **list of dictionaries**. But sometimes I receive two packets at once. They look like

```
[{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}][{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}][{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}]
```

I want to convert it into this:-

```
[{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"},
 {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(string.replace('][', ','))`

Comment: What you get is it in the form of strings ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1. Replace `][` with a `,` because those consecutive square brackets represent separate packets, and the easiest way to join them is to replace with a comma
2. Convert the string to a dictionary with `ast.literal_eval`, the "safe" `eval`.

---

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(string.replace('][', ','))

[{'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'},
 {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'},
 {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'},
 {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'},
 {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'}]
```

The assumption here is that you're receiving these "packets" as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
l='[{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}][{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}][{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}]'
```

Using `re`

```
import re
re.findall("\[?([^\]]+)?\]", l)
```

Output

```
['{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}',
 '{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}', 
 '{"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}, {"property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"}'
]
```

Comment: which of the two would be faster.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar regex is generally much slower, than pure string substitution.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I implemented the string substitution one